# Showing planes in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I have a GeoGebra diagram but I want to make a Tikz picture out of it. My goal is to make the faded green planes. The vector w-v is on the plane and m is on a plane that is parallel to that green plane as well.

So far, I have a 3D tikz picture and I've been experimenting with the best way to make this image. In my code, I have the vectors w, v, and w-v. (The vectors w and v are perpendicular, and w-v would lie on the lower green plane.) I've yet to put in vectors x, m, and y, and the plane that goes through m.

To (somewhat) prevent risk of repeating myself, I'll explain where the idea of the picture came from - it's supposed to be the general solution to Baby Rudin's 1.18. W and V are perpendicular vectors. Those two vectors, along with W-V, make a right angle triangle. H, which is the blurrly plane, is supposed to be a vector space where H is defined as v in R^k such that the dot product of v and w is 0. In other words, the space H is the hyperplane that is perpendicular to vector W. And the hyperplane perpendicular to W that passes through M is that other one. M is defined as the midpoint of segment X-Y. Sorry if that just makes it worse, but in essence, all I want is a Tikz picture that looks like the GeoGebra picture (even if the code doesn't accurately reflect the geometry, even in 3D).

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [x={(-0.6cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1]
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
     \fill[red, opacity = 0.1] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
     \draw[gray!40] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
     \fill[green, opacity = 0.1] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
     \draw[gray!40] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
     \draw[black, -latex] (0, 0) -- (5.5, 0) node[left] {$z$};
     \draw[gray, -latex] (0, 0) -- (-0.5, 0);
     \foreach \z in {1,...,5} \draw[] (\z, -0.1) -- (\z, 0.1) node[left]{\z};
     \foreach \z in {-1,...,-1} \draw[gray] (\z, -0.1) -- (\z, 0.1) node[left]{\z};
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
     \fill[blue, opacity = 0.1] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
     \draw[gray!40] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
     \draw[black, -latex] (0, 0) -- (5.5, 0) node[above] {$y$};
     \draw[black, -latex] (0, 0) -- (0, 5.5) node[above] {$x$};
     \draw[gray, -latex] (0, 0) -- (0, -0.5);
     \foreach \x in {0,...,5} \draw[] (-0.1, \x) -- (0.1, \x) node[right]{\x};
     \foreach \x in {-1,...,-1} \draw[gray] (-0.1, \x) -- (0.1, \x) node[right]{\x};
     \draw[gray, -latex] (0, 0) -- (-0.5, 0);
     \foreach \y in {1,...,5} \draw[] (\y, -0.1) -- (\y, 0.1) node[below]{\y};
     \foreach \y in {-1,...,-1} \draw[gray] (\y, -0.1) -- (\y, 0.1) node[below]{-\y};
   \end{scope}
%
   \draw[red, thick] (0, 2, 0) -- (-1, 2, 0);
   \draw[blue, thick] (-1, 2, 0) -- (-1, 2, 2);
   \draw[green, thick] (-1, 0, 0) -- (-1, 2, 0); 
   \draw[black, ultra thick, ->] (0,0,0) -- (-1,2,2) node[below right]{$\mathbf{v}$};
   %
    \draw[red, thick] (0, 1, 0) -- (4, 1, 0);
    \draw[blue, thick] (4, 1, 0) -- (4, 1, 1);
    \draw[green, thick] (4, 0, 0) -- (4, 1, 0); 
    \draw[black, ultra thick, ->] (0,0,0) -- (4,1,1) node[below left]{$\mathbf{w}$};
   %
    \draw[black, ultra thick, ->] (-1,2,2) -- (4,1,1);
    \draw[black] (2.5,1.5,1.5) node[above left]{$\mathbf{w-v}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, this question is not at all clear to me. How is it possible that "$w$, $v$, $w$ being perpendicular to $v$", i.e. `v` is perpendicular to itself? Should the plane be added to the code you present here? What is the equation of the plane?

Comment: I've updated the question. In essence, I want to make a tikz picture that looks like the GeoGebra one. I think the main thing I need is a plane that w-v can lie on

Comment: @Sat Suppose `O(0,0,0), A(1,3,5), B(3, 4, -3)`, then `w= (1,3,5)`, `v=(3,4,-3)`. The equation w - v lie on is `29 x-18 y+5 z=0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize in advance for deleting most of the code that you show, but I really cannot understand how it relates to the question. For the time being this answer only defines a way to create blurry planes.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{155,183,174}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{render blur shadow/.code={\pgfbs@savebb%
\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
\pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox%
\pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
\pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform%
\colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!#1}%
\pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{#1}%
\pgfsetfading{shadowfading}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
\pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
\pgfbs@restorebb%\globalcolorstrue
},render blur shadow/.default=shadowcolor,
shadow color/.code=\colorlet{shadowcolor}{#1},
blurry plane/.style={transform shape,fill=#1,shadow color=#1,rounded corners=2pt,
blur shadow={shadow blur steps=25,shadow scale=1.1,shadow opacity=100,
shadow xshift=0ex,shadow yshift=0ex,shadow blur radius=1.5ex}}}
\colorlet{shadowcolor}{black}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blurry planes}
\begin{center}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,>=stealth]
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
    \path node[anchor=south west,minimum size=5cm,blurry plane=mygreen]{};
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=3]
    \path node[anchor=south west,minimum size=5cm,blurry plane=mygreen]{};
   \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that draws the planes through some points. It requires the [3d tools library](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools).

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{155,183,174}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{render blur shadow/.code={\pgfbs@savebb%
\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
\pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox%
\pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
\pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform%
\colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!#1}%
\pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{#1}%
\pgfsetfading{shadowfading}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
\pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
\pgfbs@restorebb%\globalcolorstrue
},render blur shadow/.default=shadowcolor,
shadow color/.code=\colorlet{shadowcolor}{#1},
blurry plane/.style={transform shape,fill=#1,shadow color=#1,rounded corners=2pt,
blur shadow={shadow blur steps=25,shadow scale=1.1,shadow opacity=100,
shadow xshift=0ex,shadow yshift=0ex,shadow blur radius=1.5ex}}}
\colorlet{shadowcolor}{black}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\tikzset{orthonormal basis vectors of plane/.code n args={3}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mya}{TD("(#2)-(#1)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mynormalization}{1/sqrt(TD("(\mya)o(\mya)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mya}{TD("\mynormalization*(\mya)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{TD("(#3)-(#1)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mynormalization}{1/sqrt(TD("(\myb)o(\myb)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{TD("\mynormalization*(\myb)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myn}{TD("(\mya)x(\myb)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mynormalization}{1/sqrt(TD("(\myn)o(\myn)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myn}{TD("\mynormalization*(\myn)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myc}{TD("(\myn)x(\mya)")}
\tikzset{insert path={
 (\mya) coordinate(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/projections/planex})
 (\myc) coordinate(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/projections/planey})
 }}},
3d/projections/.cd,planex/.initial=planex,planey/.initial=planey}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Blurry planes}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{160}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
    (2,-2,2) coordinate (v) 
    (0,2,2) coordinate (w) 
    (-3,5,2) coordinate(m)
    [3d coordinate={(v')=(v)+(m)},
    3d coordinate={(w')=(w)+(m)}];
 \path[orthonormal basis vectors of plane={O}{v}{w}]; 
 \begin{scope}[x={(planex)},y={(planey)},canvas is xy plane at z=0,
    transform shape]
  \path node[anchor=south west,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=9cm,
    blurry plane=mygreen]{}
    (m) node[anchor=south west,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=9cm,
    blurry plane=mygreen]{};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and it's all alright if you delete most/all my code. I updated the question with the inspiration for the picture.

Comment: @Sat Thanks! I still don't quite get it. Your code produces three mutually orthogonal planes but you screen shot shows two orthogonal planes. Which of these two options, if any, should an answer provide you with?

Comment: My original code is supposed to only showcase the 3 vectors W, V, and W-V. Although I do have planes, they're not the focus. They're supposed to show the 3 different axis (or more specifically, the planes XY, XZ, and YZ) rather than actually have them be anything important. In retrospect, they probably shouldn't have been made since if I made the other two planes then it might look too busy and confusing - also it might give the impression that the answer applies only to 3 dimensions

The code/picture I want is effectively the Tikz version of the attached picture.

Comment: @Sat I think this is rather straightforward if you tell me what the 3d coordinates of `m`, `w` and `v` are.

Comment: the coordinates could be these: w=(0,2,2), v=(2,-2,2), x=(-4,6,4),y=(-2,4,0),m=(-3,5,2)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
    (1, 3, 5) coordinate (A) 
    (3, 4, -3) coordinate (B)
        (-6,5, -2) coordinate (X)
        (-453/119, 433/119, -193/119) coordinate (M)    
        (-192/119, 271/119, -148/119)  coordinate (Y)
    (-1,10,5)  coordinate (v);

\begin{scope}
    \foreach \v/\position in {B/above,O/below,A/below,X/above,Y/above,M/right} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.3pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }
    \end{scope}
        \draw[ultra thick,->] (O) -- (A) (O) -- (B) (B) -- (A);
                        \draw (-5, -10, -7) -- (-2, -1, 8) -- (5, 10, 7) -- (2, 1, -8) -- cycle (X) -- (M);

            \draw ($ (-5, -10, -7) + (v) $)-- ($ (-2, -1, 8) + (v) $) -- ($ (5, 10, 7) + (v) $) -- ($ (2, 1, -8) + (v) $)--cycle;
        \draw[dashed] (M) -- (Y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]